# Check Shiny inputs and generate warning on sidebar layout

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a shiny app that checks if an email provided in the sidebar is valid (in my case I authenticate directly to an API but in the code below I just create a toy example). I know that I can generate warnings and errors for inputs using `validate` and `need` (already read the shiny site on the topic [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html)) but on most examples the errors and warnings are shown in the `mainPanel()` when generating a plot or something a like.

In my case, the main layout is only static text. What I'm trying to achieve is simple: the user inputs an email I check it, if it doesn't comply I generate some warning/error but it is shown **somewhere** else other than the `mainPanel()` because in my case there's no dynamic `mainPanel`.

Below is an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            textInput("email", "Email")
        ),
        mainPanel()
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$email <-
      renderUI({
        validate(need(input$email == "",
               "Introduce your email"))

        validate(need(grep("gmail", input$email, value = TRUE)),
               "Your email is not valid")
      })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any idea how to achieve this? The error could be shown any where but on the `mainPanel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if I understand your question correctly, does the below do what you want? It displays a text message in the sidebar if one of your specified conditions is not met.

Hope this helps!

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("email", "Email"),
      uiOutput('email_text')
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$email_text <-
    renderUI({
      if(input$email == ""){
        return(p("Please add your gmail e-mail address."))
      }

      if(!grepl("gmail", input$email)){
        return(p("Your email is not a gmail e-mail address!"))
      }

    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Yes, something like this is a possible solution. Thanks!